# Controller Post - Duplicate Records - Mozilla Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am providing a link via Mail to the Users. When they click on link Page Opens & as they hit Submit button, Controller Post Method runs.

```
saveRecords()
{
  -- business logic
  -- code validation for checking duplicates
  -- saving records
}
```

All was working well. But suddenly it was found that duplicate records are being entered. There is no problem in Code logic.

After tracing it was found that it is happening when browser is Mozilla. And scenario is User clicks on Mail link twice so 2 tabs open & if he hits Submit button on each tab then Duplicates are being inserted.

Note - if same Page we hit submit it validates properly. 
Problem occurs when 2 tabs are open & Submit button is clicked in both tabs & Browser is Firefox.

Can you suggest me a solution?

This is summary of Code :-

```
var obj = ctx.tblDuty.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == recordId);

if (obj.EntryStatus == Status.Approved)
    msg = "Duty already Approved.!";
else if (obj.EntryStatus == Status.Rejected)
    msg = "Duty already Rejected.!";

var data = service.saveDuty(model, userRole);
```

Comment: In your code snippet, you have _-- code validation for checking duplicates_ - but you say duplicates are being added - is that code not working correctly?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Code working 100% correctly. When code is hit 2 times from separate tabs then Code is running for 2 times simultaneously one after another. Before Saving on 1st time hit, 2nd time Code is also running it finds that Record is not yet saved because 1st time Code is still running.

Comment: @Anup ASP.NET MVC is *not* a data access library. It doesn't store anything. You are probably asking about *Entity Framework*. The browser doesn't matter if your data code inserts duplicates. Post your *data access code*, where you insert or update entries, the DbContext configuration. What you posted doesn't show any attempt to check for existing records or anything that *stores* or *updates* records

Comment: Sorry, I'm not convinced - saving the data might take 50-100 ms (a user could not click to buttons in 2 separate tabs in that time)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Saving Data is preceded by business logic. When 1st time code is in Business Logic & records are not yet saved at that time 2nd time Code has jumped from the validations as in the above mentioned Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you introduce a lock around the method (if you can't figure out why Mozilla sends two POST calls) and wrap the code in there:

```
static object _lock = new object();
saveRecords()
{
    lock(_lock)
    {
        -- business logic
        -- code validation for checking duplicates
        -- saving records
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1** [Blocking Collection with working rows]:
[image]

**This is not the best solution, but it will get it done for you. Maybe consider using Monitor if you wanna do it in a better\more optimal way.**

Comment: Thanks . i will try this

Comment: Does the lock occurs for same session? If some another User from another System tries to access Controller at the same time, will he be able to do?

Comment: The lock is universal (static) for all the users. If 100 users send a request on this page, the lock will lock each one of them separately and it wont allow a next request to this method to get processes until the previous finishes. It will process 1 action at a time. If you dont want this, you'll probably need to use a static lists and put recordId in there (you'll remove it after the save finished or fails), and if the same recordId comes to get processed you will reject it (or do whatever you want). Or control if you should lock by a bool sent from the client side (query string or whatever)

Comment: @Anup please see the image above, and the results in the console window. Feel free to ask anything that might be bugging you and sorry on the late response. The threads are like the web calls a user would do (clicking the same button multiple times, duplicate Firefox calls in your case and so on).

Comment: The lock is universal (static) for all the users - That will not be the case if this system is run behind a load balancer

Comment: @3dd I've never used a load balancer before, what would be the solution in that scenario?